# Deleting records before a certain date

Tags: mysql, datetime, delete-row

How would I go about deleting all records from a MySQL table from before a certain date, where the date column is in DATETIME format?

An example datetime is `2011-09-21 08:21:22`.

Answer (score 161, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE date < '2011-09-21 08:21:22';
```

Answer (score 27):

This helped me delete data based on different attributes. This is dangerous so make sure you back up database or the table before doing it:

```
mysqldump -h hotsname -u username -p password database_name > backup_folder/backup_filename.txt
```

Now you can perform the delete operation:

```
delete from table_name where column_name < DATE_SUB(NOW() , INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

This will remove all the data from before one day. For deleting data from before 6 months:

```
delete from table_name where column_name < DATE_SUB(NOW() , INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
```

Comment: That was just what I needed, thanks.  Only confusion for me was that you have to write "6 MONTH" not "6 MONTHS" as MySQL doesn't recognize it. This is a great way to keep audit logs manageable.

Answer (score 14):

To show result till yesterday

```
WHERE DATE(date_time) < CURDATE()
```

To show results of 10 days

```
WHERE date_time < NOW() - INTERVAL 10 DAY
```

To show results before 10 days

```
WHERE DATE(date_time) < DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 10 DAY)
```

These will work for you

You can find dates like this

```
SELECT DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 11 DAY)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another example using defined column/table names.

```
DELETE FROM jos_jomres_gdpr_optins WHERE `date_time` < '2020-10-21 08:21:22';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for Oracle SQL,then it might help:

```
Delete from table_name WHERE column_name < sysdate - INTERVAL '10' DAY
```

And do check on the format that sysdate is returing.