# Drop MySQL rows where date is less than today

Tags: php, mysql, date

I've got a column `date`, which has a specific format.
`dd/mm/yyyy` (for ex `31/05/2018`). How can i drop rows where `date` is less than today?

I'm using MySQL5 & PHP7.

`EDIT`
I know it's a simple operation, but actually my date format is "weird", i tried doing

`DELETE FROM table WHERE date < '26/06/2017'`, but it's actually deleting columns aged 2018.

Comment: do you mean delete rows where column is less then date?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deleting records before a certain date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359457/deleting-records-before-a-certain-date)

Comment: This is a pretty simple, common type of operation. Have you searched for a solution? Have you tried anything?

Comment: why have you stored dates other than using a `DATE` type? You're storing it as plain text and this poses issues and you have to CAST that now.

Comment: What you need is `STR_TO_DATE()` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Comment: Thank you, i think i'm going to use DATE SQL format anyway.

Comment: Store dates using the correct data type. Or don't bother with a MySQL database.

Answer (score -2):

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE date < NOW()
```

Comment: are you 100% sure about this? Look at their dating format again.

Comment: had they used the proper column type, then your answer would have worked. This wasn't the case, unfortunately.

Comment: Agreed sorry take a look here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861489/converting-a-date-in-mysql-from-string-field